# Como puedo usar un OR dentro de un if en php

Tags: php, mysql

¿Se puede usar un **OR** dentro de un **if**?

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
$sql3="select * from observacion_preguntas where refen_observacion='$pro'";
$ok3=mysql_query($sql3,$con);

    while(($producto3=mysql_fetch_assoc($ok3))>0){


if(strlen($producto3['fotoa'])>10){

    $tabla.="<table><tr><td>FOTO EVIDENCIA:</td><td><img src='".$producto3['fotoa']."' width='400' /></td></tr></table>";
}else{
    $tabla.="";
}
    $tabla.="";
     }
```

Esto lo que hace es traerme una imagen registrada de un formulario, en el caso de que el formulario registrado no tenga imagen insertada entonces que no me muestre nada.

El problema es que tengo dos columnas mas en la base de datos que me guardan otras fotos los campos se llaman: *fotoc* y *fotob*

El problema es que al intentar imprimir las demás fotos en el **php** si no están insertadas me saca un error.

### Ejemplo:

Registro 1 tiene *fotoa* insertada pero *fotob* y *fotoc* no hay nada, con la consulta de arriba no tengo problema me muestra la foto, pero cuando intento imprimir las otras variables de *fotob* y *fotoc* me saca un **error** porque esos campos no tienen foto.

Registro 2 tiene *fotoa*, *fotob* y *fotoc* si me funciona la consulta que trae todas las fotos.

Entonces estaba pensando en incluir un **OR** dentro del **if** y colocar que verifique las otras variables de *fotob* y *fotoc*, o ¿De que forma podría hacerlo?

Comment: IF te va a evaluar cualquier expresión que pueda reducirse a una evaluación lógica. Es decir, sí se puede. Lo importante es hacerlo bien :) Inténtalo y trae el resultado!

Comment: esto: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.logical.php?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:
Con `Or = ||` o con un `AND &&`

```
$sql3="select * from observacion_preguntas where refen_observacion='$pro'";
$ok3=mysql_query($sql3,$con);

    while(($producto3=mysql_fetch_assoc($ok3))>0){


if(strlen($producto3['fotoa']) > 10 || strlen($producto3['fotoa']) > 20){

    $tabla.="<table><tr><td>FOTO EVIDENCIA:</td><td><img src='".$producto3['fotoa']."' width='400' /></td></tr></table>";
}else{
  $tabla.="";
  }
  $tabla.="";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas un OR, sino analizar cada columna para saber si hay una imagen o no.

```
$sql3="select * from observacion_preguntas where refen_observacion='$pro'";
$ok3=mysql_query($sql3,$con);
$tabla = '';
while($producto3=mysql_fetch_assoc($ok3)) {
    // Crear variable para juntar las imágenes
    $imagenes = '';
    // Hay imagen en fotoa?
    if($producto3['fotoa'] != '') {
        $imagenes .= "<img src=\"{$producto3['fotoa']}\" style=\"width:400px;\">";
    }
    // Hay imagen en fotob?
    if($producto3['fotob'] != '') {
        $imagenes .= "<img src=\"{$producto3['fotob']}\" style=\"width:400px;\">";
    }
    // Hay imagen en fotoc?
    if($producto3['fotoc'] != '') {
        $imagenes .= "<img src=\"{$producto3['fotoc']}\" style=\"width:400px;\">";
    }
    // Hay imágenes?, crear la tabla
    if($imagenes != '') {
        $tabla .= "<table><tr><td>Foto evidencia:</td><td>$imagenes</td></tr></table>";
    }
}
```

**Nota:** No me gusta concatenar, prefiero encerrar todo entre comillas dobles, escapar las comillas internas e incluir elementos de array u objetos entre llaves.